# Custom CMS page XML identifier when URL key contains a "/"

Tags: magento2, xml, custom, cms-pages

I need to create an XML file for a custom CMS page but the URL key contains a "/":

i.e. my/page-id

Is there a way to do the equivalent to cms_page_view_id_my/page-id.xml for this? I've tried replacing the slash with a dash (cms_page_view_id_my-page-id.xml) but to no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The URL key of the page with any forward slash (/) replaced by an underscore (_).

So You need to use `cms_page_view_id_my_page-id.xml`

For more reference read [user Guide](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/layout-update-place-block.html#step-2-compose-the-layout-update-in-xml)